# Sync eWon Module with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ewon

I am working on the eWon Module in which i am able to get access his eWon Machines data value but i want that all data inside the SQL Server So My Question is that i am not able to find any help to set up ewon Machine reading  data to the SQL Server.

Please help me to find How to store data of eWon Module in SQL Server.

i was also read out [THIS](http://wiki.ewon.biz/@api/deki/files/1895/=RG-004-0-EN(M2Web_API_Reference_Guide).pdf) guide

I am Working on this:http://ewon.biz/

Please help me and Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

eWON (the company) just released a super easy way to collect historical data from your eWON router to your back-end server. They call it the Talk2M DataMailbox. [More info on their developer web site](http://developer.ewon.biz/content/datamailbox)